# change event not triggering for first option value

Tags: jquery, html

i have a menu html select tag having some menus like:

```
<select class="menu">
    <option value="1">One</option>
    <option value="2">Two</option>
    <option value="3">Three</option>
    <option value="4">Four</option>
    <option value="5">Five</option>
</select>
```

I'm listening for the option selection for `change` event.

```
$(".menu").change(function (evt) {
    alert($(evt.target).val())

})
```

problem is the first option value(One) is already selected and on option does not trigger `change` event for that option.

http://jsfiddle.net/navyad/Yfs4u/205/

any way around this ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You should `trigger` it for the first time,

```
$(".menu").change(function (evt) {
    alert($(evt.target).val())
}).change(); // or .trigger('change');
```

### [DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/Yfs4u/206/)

Comment: selecting "One" from dropdown very first time, still does not trigger event.

Comment: @naveenyadav Logically that wont trigger the change event, see changing from `0 - 1` would trigger the change but not in case of `0 - 0`

Answer (score 1):

You could add a dummy value:

```
<select class="menu">
    <option value="">Select one...</option>
```

Comment: Maybe OP does something with the value when the page loads, so this is not a good solution.

Comment: @putvande Maybe, maybe not. OP didn't say what the end goal was, so it's hard for anyone but OP to say if it's a good solution or not.

Answer (score 1):

I struggled with this for so long and the suggestion by @holmes2136 to add a trigger worked for me. Thanks.

```
$(".menu").change(function (evt) {
   alert($(evt.target).val());
}).trigger('change');
```

Answer (score 0):

Try the following code

```
$(".menu").change(function (evt) {
   alert($(evt.target).val());
}).trigger('change');
```

Answer (score 0):

I just had this problem today. You can solve the problem this way:

Just set initially the select tag without any value and then all options will be able to select:

```
document.querySelector('.menu').value = '';
```

Then add your addEventListener.